# Multiple foreign keys to different tables on a single id

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a rather complicated relationship between the tweets and its author. In my system, I have 3 sources which can be related to a tweet (teams, players and persons). The issue is that instead of having a teamId, personId and teamId in each tweet and only one of them is not null. I've come up with below solution with a relational table called `created`. However the issue is that I'm not sure it is possible to create a foreign key from the sourceId to all 3 ids in Teams, Players and Persons tables? What can I do in order to create the right table structure for this type of system?

To explain the Created table further it contains free columns:

**id** = primary key and auto_increment

**sourceType** = enum can be (persons, teams or Players). By doing this i know whether it is a person, team or player

**sourceId** = is the id of the particular person, team or player.

---

**Players**

```
id
name
image
twitter_user
teamId
```

**Teams**

```
id
name
twitter_user
```

**Persons**

```
id
name
image
twitter_user
teamId
```

**Tweet**
    id
    created
    text
    createdId

**Created**

```
id
sourcetype
sourceId
```

[image]

Comment: Would your problem not go away if all 3 types of entities could fit in a single table? :)

Comment: yes but i'm not sure you can unless you can put them together and still distinquish between the 3 types?

Comment: Exactly, you could have `entities` table that contains what your `create` table does. Then what's left is that you have a table for each of the entity types which hold the information needed. Instead of `enum` for the type, you could have `entities_types` table and link it via foreign keys. Alternatively, you can ditch what I wrote, use your `create` table and add 3 columns - one for each type that you have. If something is a `player` type, the column contains a number, the rest contain null (fks can be null). That solves your issue immediately.

Comment: The come the issue regarding that players then is not connected to a team, which is necessary for the system to work